# The Card Game War With processing

Tags: java, arrays, processing

Ok So in my class were working on the card game War but I have to use processing and I need to create a non repeating random number generator for this to work. I know in regular IDEs I can just use `Collection.shuffle` but processing doesn't have that any one know a way to make a random non repeating number

```
void mousePressed() { 
    imageMode(CENTER);
    isDraw = true;
    isDraw2 = true;
    if(isDraw){
    int n = int(random(card.length)); 
    /// I should make this an array but Collection.shuffle 
    /// doesn't work
    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
       if (n == i) {
           Card[i] = false; 
           println(n+1+" human "+Card[i]);
       }

       if (Card[n]) {
           image(card[n], width/2, height/2-120);
       }
   }
```

Comment: I have a strong feeling that googling `random number in Java` wouldn't be so hard.

Comment: @alex then remove stackoverflow, is never more useful

Comment: `Collections.shuffle()` has nothing to do with IDEs.

Answer (score 4):

Import java.util.Random

```
import java.util.Random;
```

and this piece of code will get a random between 0 and 100.

```
Random random = new Random();
random.nextInt(100); //Get random between 0 and 100.
```

It is recommended that you create a Random outside the method and the method uses it if you need to call that method several times.

if You want to generate no repeated values, init them in a List.

```
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//fill with 0 to 10 elements.
```

then call method to get random

```
Integer rand = random.nextInt(values.size());
Integer cardId = values.get(rand);
values.remove(rand);
```

the above snippet of code will get a preinitialized value from list and remove it so it is not "generated" again.

Answer (score 0):

In Processing you don't need to import Random.

You have a random method available:

```
random(10);
```

This will give you a random number between 0.0 and 9.9.

```
random(2, 4);
```

This will give you random numbers between 2.0 and 3.9.